# Proving an upper bound for solutions with divisibility

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

> Suppose $m,n,k$ are positive integers with $m-1|kn-1$ and $n-1|km-1$. Is it true that the largest solution $(m,n)$ with $m\ge n$ has $m=k^3$? If not, is there an upper bound in terms of $k$ for what $\max\{m,n\}$ can be?

This question follows from numerical conjecture - indeed, if we have $k=3$ the largest possible value for $m$ is $27$; $64$ in [the case $k=4$](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4764613/242) and $125$ in the case $k=5$. I don't know how to prove it though. An attempt would be to say that the first divisibiltiy requires $kn-1=a(m-1)$ for some $a\in\mathbb{N}$, so $n=\frac{1+am-a}{k}$, and then the second divisibility gives that there is a positive integer $b$ such that $km-1=bn-b$. Substitute in the above result to see that $km-1+b=\frac{b+bam-ba}{k}$. Hence \begin{equation}k^2m-k+kb=b+bam-ba\end{equation}which then reduces to \begin{equation}m(k^2-ba)-k+kb-b+ba=0\end{equation} so $m(k^2-ba)+k(b-1)+b(a-1)=0$. I can't see how to bound $m$ from this though. Alternatively, we could maybe write this in terms of $k$ but I don't see how this would help.

Comment: Do not delete your question after getting an answer.  This is disrespectful to the person or people who took the time to answer your question, and disrespectful to future users who might find your question and its answer(s) helpful.

Answer (score 2):

You've made a great start. Your conjecture is correct, i.e., for each $k \ge 2$, with $m \ge n$, the largest value of $m$ is $m = k^3$.

With your last equation, and using some of the reasoning in your linked [case $k = 4$ answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4764613/602049), we get

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
m(k^2 - ba) + k(b - 1) + b(a - 1) & = 0 \\
m(ba - k^2) & = k(b - 1) + b(a - 1) \\
m(ab - k^2) & = ab + (k - 1)b - k
\end{aligned}\end{equation}\tag{1}\label{eq1A}$$

Using $a = b = 1$ gives $m(1 - k^2) = 0$. However, this requires $m = 0$, but it's not allowed since $a$, $b$ and $m$ are positive integers. For all other positive values of $a$ and $b$, the RHS of \eqref{eq1A} is positive, so then $ba - k^2 \gt 0$, i.e., there's an integer $c \gt 0$ where

$$ab - k^2 = c \;\to\; ab = c + k^2 \tag{2}\label{eq2A}$$

Dividing both sides of \eqref{eq1A} by $c$, and using \eqref{eq2A}, we have

$$m = \frac{c + k^2 + (k - 1)b - k}{c} \tag{3}\label{eq3A}$$

For any fixed $c$, and since $k$ is fixed, the value of $m$ above is maximized with the largest possible value of $b$. The RHS of \eqref{eq2A} shows this occurs when $a = 1$, to get $b = c + k^2$. Substituting this into \eqref{eq3A} gives

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
m & \le \frac{c + k^2 + (k - 1)(c + k^2) - k}{c} \\
& = \frac{c + k^2 + ck + k^3 - c - k^2 - k}{c} \\
& = \frac{ck + k^3 - k}{c} \\
& = k + \frac{k^3 - k}{c}
\end{aligned}\end{equation}\tag{4}\label{eq4A}$$

Since $k^3 - k \gt 0$, then $c$ increasing causes the RHS to decrease, so the maximum value of the RHS occurs where $c = 1$, to then get

$$m \le k + k^3 - k = k^3 \tag{5}\label{eq5A}$$

Your first divisibility result with $a = 1$ then gives

$$kn - 1 = a(m - 1) \;\;\to\;\; kn = k^3 \;\;\to\;\; n = k^2 \tag{6}\label{eq6A}$$

The original divisibility requirements are met since

$$m - 1 \mid kn - 1 \;\;\to\;\; k^3 - 1 \mid k^3 - 1, \;\;\; n - 1 \mid km - 1 \;\;\to\;\; k^2 - 1 \mid k^4 - 1 \tag{7}\label{eq7A}$$

with the latter part using that $k^4 - 1 = (k^2 - 1)(k^2 + 1)$. This confirms that the maximum $m = k^3$ gives a valid solution of $(m, n) = (k^3, k^2)$.